# why is that we cannot achieve coding gain with repetitive code (n,1) even though the minimum Hamming distance increases with 'n'?

Tags: coding-theory

Intuitively we are supposed to achieve a coding gain with repetitive code for n>2 with a decrease in overall rate.

We are considering AWGN channel.

Surprisingly, repetitive code performs worse in AWGN channel (that is, no coding gain). Even a convolutional code with lesser minimum Hamming distance (dmin) achieves some coding gain. But repetitive code (n,1) does not achieve any coding gain.

Why is it so?

P.S: Performance measure: BER (bit-error-rate)  vs  SNR (signal-to-noise ratio) per bit (Eb/No).

Comment: It's more of how you interpret "gain". If you look at BER vs Es/No then there's definitely a "gain" : you get a lower BER for a given Es/No when you encode. When you use Eb/No as a measure of SNR then for this code (only) you lose that gain because this code is as inefficient as you can get...so "coding efficiency" might have been a better name for "coding gain" but that's not standard lingo.

Comment: "Intuitively we are supposed to achieve a coding gain with repetitive code for n>2 with a decrease in overall rate." Not intuitive for me. What we can expect is a decrease of prob. of error - but the consequent "decrease in overall rate" implies that we need more power per source symbol. That is, the "decrease in overall rate" is not a separate feature that we could weight against the "coding gain"; rather the latter (measured with Eb/No) implicitly includes the former.